# Flutter - Remove drawer icon in scaffold

Tags: android, flutter, drawer

i'm trying to remove the burger drawer icon in flutter, but I don't find any solution. I don't have an appbar, so I can't hide it changing leading attribute.
This is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: Container()
            ),
          body: Container()
        ),
    );
  }
```

Edit: This is the icon
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In App bar set automaticallyImplyLeading property  to false and it won't appear

Answer (score 1):

I just find out what was happening. It was not a Scaffold problem, it happened when I added an AppBar. I didn't have one in the Scaffold, but inside it I have an NestedScrollView where I used and SliverAppBar that created that icon, you can easily hide it by using: `leading: Container()` inside any appbar

Comment: This helped - iirc SizedBox.shrink() is recommended for an empty widget

Answer (score 1):

If you are using drawer use this line to hide inside AppBar() widget

```
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
```

and if you are using end drawer use it

```
  actions: <Widget>[Container()],
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no drawer icon in the code above. I just ran it. If you don't want a drawer then you shouldn't supply one. Just leave it null. See image below for the result your code produces. [image]

Comment: I need the drawer, but It has to be hidden, so I can only show it by pressing another button. Check the picture I added in the post info, the icon is white, that's why it's not showing in your app.